# Variance of a random variable between 0 and c.

Tags: probability

[image]

My professor says we need to know how to solve a problem like this for our upcoming exam and I can't find anything in my textbook or notes related to this at all. Can anybody help make this understandable?

Comment: This result is known as [Popoviciu's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Popoviciu%27s_inequality_on_variances) and has a proof over on [Stack Overflow](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45588/variance-of-a-bounded-random-variable).

Comment: @JMoravitz - not important but that site is actually called *Cross Validated*, for statistics rather than *Stack Overflow*'s  coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint would suggest looking at $E[X^2] = E[X\times X] \le E[cX] = cE[X]$ since $0 \le X \le c$.

Your next stage would be to look at $\text{Var}(X)=E[X^2] - E[X]^2 \le cE[X] - E[X]^2 = c^2\alpha - c^2\alpha^2 = c^2[\alpha(1-\alpha)]$ using the suggestion involving $\alpha$.

Now take the derivative with respect to $\alpha$ of $c^2[\alpha(1-\alpha)]$  to find which value of $\alpha$ in the interval $[0,1]$ maximises that expression and so what the maximum of that expression is - clearly the intended maximum is $\frac{c^2}{4}$ if you are to conclude $\text{Var}(X) \le   \frac{c^2}{4}$.